# Boostrap image not responsive in safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, safari

I  realized my website is not working on safari (desktop and mobile). For some reason the images are not responsive. I used a Bootstrap theme, the website is simple. Please help!

website: [www.scanek.com](http://www.scanek.com)

HTML:

```
<section id="portfolio" class="pfblock">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

                <div class="pfblock-header wow fadeInUp">
                    <h2 class="pfblock-title">Categories</h2>
                    <div class="pfblock-subtitle">

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div><!-- .row -->


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="grid wow zoomIn">
                    <a href="categories/kitchen/index.html">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="assets/images/kitchens.jpg" alt="img01" class="img-responsive" />
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2> <span>Kitchens</span></h2>
                            <p></p>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="grid wow zoomIn">
                    <a href="categories/bathroom//bathroom1/index.html">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="assets/images/bathrooms.jpg" alt="img01"/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2> <span>Bathrooms</span></h2>
                            <p></p>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="grid wow zoomIn">
                   <a href="categories/fixtures/index.html">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                        <img src="assets/images/fixtures.jpg" alt="img01"/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2>House<span> Fixtures</span></h2>
                            <p></p>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


    </div><!-- .container -->

</section>
```

CSS:

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.grid figure img {
position: relative;
display: block;
min-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
opacity: 0.8;

}

figure.effect-bubba img {
opacity: 0.75;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
transition: opacity 0.35s;
}
```

Comment: where does your css come form..? because i suspect `width: 100%` specifying the size might override bootstrap's.

Comment: The css code came from bootstrap. the img {} code I added in response of other threats trying to help, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your css syntaks on link that you provide to us is not right, for the start, 
you have:

```
img {
    max-width: 100% width :100% height: auto;
}
```

try with :

```
img {
 max-width: 100%;
 width :100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

after yo fix this issues, then if problem is still there we can try to help you..

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I already fix it but nothing happened. Safari is the problem. In any other web browser it works.

Comment: tested on safari: iphone6s, tabler air , and latest desktop safary everything is ok with images

Answer (score 0):

In addiion to the CSS typo on `img` `width`(should be width: 100%;), you had `.img-reponsive` only on one image set.

Set `.img-responsive` on all images.

Check resizing on following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/5mfvj9v2/20/

Snippet below:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.grid figure img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

figure.effect-bubba img {
  opacity: 0.75;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="portfolio" class="pfblock">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <div class="pfblock-header wow fadeInUp">
          <h2 class="pfblock-title">Categories</h2>
          <div class="pfblock-subtitle">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="grid wow zoomIn">
          <a href="categories/kitchen/index.html">
            <figure class="effect-bubba">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/200x500" alt="img01" class="img-responsive" />
              <figcaption>
                <h2> <span>Kitchens</span></h2>
                <p></p>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="grid wow zoomIn">
          <a href="categories/bathroom//bathroom1/index.html">
            <figure class="effect-bubba">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/200x500" alt="img01" class="img-responsive" />
              <figcaption>
                <h2> <span>Bathrooms</span></h2>
                <p></p>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="grid wow zoomIn">
          <a href="categories/fixtures/index.html">
            <figure class="effect-bubba">
              <img src="https://placehold.it/200x500" alt="img01" class="img-responsive" />
              <figcaption>
                <h2>House<span> Fixtures</span></h2>
                <p></p>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .container -->
</section>
```